# Extremely hard binary classification problem

Tags: classification, svm, supervised-learning

Could anyone point me to a collection of binary classification dataset where a support vector machine algorithm will miserably fail?

Comment: You mean problem where SVM will fail, but other algorithms not, or any algorithm would fail, or something else?

Comment: Yes: any problem where there is a high noise to signal ratio. That’s a large domain.

Comment: SVM's dont do well with a lot of columns either, so look for a wide dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for a free LendingClub.com account and download their loan data. You can join multiple files to predict loan default. This is not a particularly easy outcome to predict (AUC 0.71). I've gotten SVM's to be about 0.67, but that is with a whole lot of fancy pre-processing so I can imagine they'd be pretty terrible right out of the box.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's a real-life dataset that does not give any guarantees that SVM would fail on it "miserably". Also, AUC 0.67 vs 0.71 does not sound like a "miserable failure".

Comment: I guess fails miserably is a subjective term. I was referring to the difference of SVM vs other algorithm families... otherwise they might have asked for a dataset that is hard-to-predict and gets low AUC without specifying the algorithm.